# How can I create a fallback for a series of JavaScript if statements?

Tags: javascript

So I want to do something that would allow me to have a form or text field ( tag in html) and basically I can type something into that field and have something else happen

For example:

```
if (x === "something") {
    then do this set of instructions
}

if (x === "something else") {
    then do this different set of instructions
}

else {
  alert("Some error message")
}
```

In the example above, is it possible to do something where I can type "something" and have it do that set on instructions but not show the alert in the `else {}` statement?

The different sets of instructions are different and the "something" and "something else" are also different, but the x is in reference to the  tag which is inside a  tag.

But basically if any of the "if" statements are met, do not execute the "else" statement. But if any of the "if" statements are not met, then execute the else statement. Not sure if it's possible, but I have no clue, just started working with js, so sorry if this is a very basic thing.

Comment: sure, just write `else if (something else)`.

Comment: All the answers assume that the poster only wants to execute a single one of the `if` statements, whereas I'm not sure the wording supports that- it seems as though they want to be able to execute multiple `if` statements, and _not_ execute the `else` if _any_ of the `if` statements are entered.

Comment: @AlexanderNied There's probably better ways for me to do it, but I have multiple `if` statements and if any of the `if` statements are executed, then do not execute the `else` statement, and vice versa, but the `else if` statements got me basically what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
if(x === "something") {
  then do this set of instructions
} else if (x === "something else") {
  then do this different set of instructions
} else {
  alert("Some error message")
}
```

Plus, the answer is kind of obvious!

Comment: Oh else if statements are a thing. To make sure, that basically says if x === "something" or "something else" it will do that set of instructions, but if x is not "something" or "something else" it will alert the error message? If that's the case, that's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks

Comment: Update: That did exactly what I wanted, thanks for the help. Didn't know if else if statements were a thing

Comment: Go to https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp to learn about if, else, and if else statements.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

```
switch(x) {
  case 'something': {
    do this set of instructions;
    break;
  }
  case 'somethingelse': {
    do this other set;
    break;
  }
  default: {
    some error message 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This... Is exactly how if statements work if I understood correctly. If a condition is True, execute this set of instructions. If it's not, execute this other set of instructions (alert an error)

Though you might be referring to the `else if` statement. In this case, else will only run if `x` isn't equal to `something else`.
Change the code to:

```js
if (x === "something") {
    then do this set of instructions
} else if (x === "something else") {
    then do this different set of instructions
} else {
  alert("Some error message")
}
```

And you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your wording, you would like to be able to execute any arbitrary number of `if` statements, and then not execute your `else` if *any* of the `if` statements have been entered.  There is not a native built-in logic structure that does this, but it can be easily achieved using a variable in the containing scope that is flipped if any of the `if` statements is entered:

```js
let enteredAnIf = false;

if (aThing) {
    // do some stuff
    enteredAnIf = true;
}

if (aDifferentThing) {
    // do some different stuff
    enteredAnIf = true;
}

if (!enteredAnIf) {
    // this is your "else", entered only if none of the above `if` 
    // statements flips the `enteredAnIf` to `true`
}
```